# same result in independent sample t test and one way anova

Tags: math, statistics, spss

I have a data set on which I performed an Independent sample t-test and a one way ANOVA, using SPSS. I got same p-values in both tests.

How is it possible to have same p-values in both tests?

Comment: There is both a statistics and a maths stack exchange site.  This is where you should ask programming questions (so if you had a problem with your spss code) but for analysis of stats you should ask at statistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree with dave, unless you want to know whether you did something wrong with SPSS (in which case you'll have to show use what you did), the right place for this question is rather statistics.stackexchange.com . And they'll want to know more about your data set and what you are trying to do. But in any case, both tests test the same null hypothesis: the t-test tests whether the population means of two compared groups are equal and one-way ANOVA does this for the population means of multiple defined groups.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in a simple case, they are the same test.